Can I add PowerShell Core 7 capabilities in PoSh 5
I have a mixed bag of modules I'm trying to stitch together into a coherent AZ DevOps release process.  Several of these modules only support up to PowerShell 5.1, however, the features I'm trying to leverage are in PowerShell 7 - specifically the ForeEach-Object -Parallel cmdlet.
Does it seem realistic that using Add-Type 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core' within the function from which I will call the ForeEach-Object -Parallel.  The scriptblock calls a self-contained script that can run as either PoSh 5 or 7.  I know that I can inline the download and use of some modules (i.e. ThreadJobs show up in 6).  Doc's say I cannot use Import-Module.
The features I'm most desiring to use of ForEach-Object are: -Parallel (obvious) -ThrottleLimit and -AsJob.
In the alternative... would it make sense to stay in 7 and "downgrade" to 5 for the Modules that don't support 7?
I'm using this as part of a multi-tenant DB release process for a little over 200+ databases.  Some DBs are big and take a while, others not so much. There's are a mixture of ~70 scripts that I apply and include backup, applying MDM data, release, rollback (for failure), and status reporting.
Insight and guidance will be appreciated.
I tried download & import of ThreadJob module from PoSh 6 and have had limited success with this.  I hope leveraging 7 with FEO -Parallel will solve my issue.

ForEach-Object -Parallel is in System.Management.Automation.dll so what you're asking for is not feasible. You can't Add-Type pwsh 7 SMA assembly in pwsh 5.1. If you're looking for a ForEach-Object -Parallel alternative for pwsh 5.1 this might be of interest: https://github.com/santisq/PSParallelPipeline same capabilities except for -AsJob

Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon, I was afraid this would be the case.
With your permission, I'd like to explore an idea.
Create 2 scripts ~ control.ps1 (define & control $jobs += ForEach-Object -Parallel { start worker script block } -AsJob -ThrottleLimit $t ... ) and work.ps1 (does the actual work).  Then, back in my original script (Main.ps1) I call Start-Process pwsh -ScriptBlock { ~ startcontrol.ps1 with parameters ~ }  which runs and monitors results from Work.ps1 jobs
Does that seem possible.
